# How to skip the NULL line in java?

Tags: java, readline

My program need to read .txt file and store it in to Arraylist.

But readLine() Stop reading after finishing  A , B , and got Error ( when reading Blankline everything return NULL and got outbound exception)

.txt file

A
B

C

D
E

Does its possible to read , skipping blankline , read again , detect blankline and skip it again .......

```
    public static void loadData(){
    try{
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("/Users/Homura/Documents/newWorkspace/DataStructures/src/flights.txt"));

    while(true){

        String myLine = rd.readLine();
        String fName = myLine.substring(0,myLine.indexOf("->",0));
        String toName = myLine.substring(myLine.indexOf("->")+3);

        if(!myMap.containsKey(fName)){
           ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
           myMap.put(fName,myArray); 
        }
        myMap.get(fName).add(toName);
        allPlaces.add(fName);

        if(rd.readLine()== null) { myLine = rd.readLine();
       }
    }
    }

    catch(IOException ex){
        throw new ErrorException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpick: a String that is `null` is not the same thing as a String that is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It is a lot easier:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Homura/Documents/newWorkspace/DataStructures/src/flights.txt");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  if (!line.equals("")) {
    //do stuff with the line since it isn't blank
}
```

This way you keep reading until the end of the file, and you only do stuff with lines that aren't blank.

You might also want to consider running the line through something like `line.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` to ensure the blank lines are truly blank and don't have other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'null line' in Java. If `readLine()` returns `null` it means end of stream, which you have to check every time you call it, and if you get it close the stream and stop reading. Your loop should look like this:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
in.close();
```

There is no such thing as 'outbound exception' either. Did you mean `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?` or `NullPointerException?`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But your Exception doesn't come from that. It's from null being applied `indexOf()` (see your exception stack trace, READ IT, that's a valuable source where you can track your errors). You use `readLine()` improperly. This:

```
if(rd.readLine()== null) { myLine = rd.readLine();
}
```

will throw away every odd line. You CAN'T check for null by calling `readLine()`. Instead you should call `readLine()` only once in the loop and check its RETURN VALUE for null. And only if it's not null you should do further processing.

Comment: @EJP: I mean, it won't just check what the next line will be, as AFAIU what the OP expects, but also read it.

Comment: In other words you mean it will throw the line away? Your answer doesn't say that. All I/O `reads the I/O buffer`, insofar as that means anything at all.

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to the way the OP uses I/O method call to check for null, instead of its result. Get it?

Comment: I understand the point you are trying to make, and it is made in my own answer, but you haven't expressed it clearly or indeed correctly. 'Will read the I/O buffer as well' is basically meaningless. Try again.

Comment: You need to stop talking about I/O buffers altogether. I fixed it for you. I don't know why you didn't just write what you actually meant.

Comment: I'm trying to put myself in the OP position, where he doesn't seem to understand the semantic of readLine(). but maybe you're right, talking about "line" is a better way than "I/O buffer"...

Answer (score 1):

you are not getting exception because of anything being null. But because of this line

```
String fName = myLine.substring(0,myLine.indexOf("->",0));
```

as, `myLine.indexOf("->",0)` returns -1, so substring method throws the exception. Modify this code to get it working.

and don't use while(true), it will be in while loop forever. use

```
while(rd.readLine() != null)
```

instead.

Comment: All that accomplishes is to throw every odd-numbered line away, and doesn't actually solve the problem either.